# Phantomjs - Reading cookies dropped via js

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs

Ok, so I am trying to read cookies from a given web page with phantom js. Basically I have the following script in the page.open() block :

```
response.cookies = page.evaluate(function () {
    return document.cookie
});
```

Now this returns cookies as expected, however, only the ones dropped server side. I want to be able to read cookies dropped via javascript. So I went through phantom's API since this is my first time using it.

I'm thinking that on page.open(), the script that drops the cookies is not executed yet, and therefore no cookies will be returned.

I tried using the page.onLoadFinsihed() callback, but that doesn't ensure that all the scripts where executed either.

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(status){
    return procedure.execute(status);
};

procedure.execute = function (status) {

    if (status === 'success') {

        try {

            response.content = page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
            });

            response.cookies = page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.cookie
            });

        } catch(e) {

            response.status  = 500;
            response.content = e.message;
        }
    }

    response.console = logs;

    system.stderr.write(debug.join('\n') + '\n');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));

    phantom.exit();
};
```

I also tried setTimeout() prior to calling document.cookie, but still can't get any cookies dropped via js to show up. Help appreciated.

Here's a minimal, complete example :

> read_cookies.js

```
var page       = require('webpage').create(),
    system     = require('system');

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: read_ccokies.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        } else {
            phantom.addCookie({
                'name': 'mycookie',
                'value': 'cookie value',
                'domain': 'domain.com'
            });

            console.log('Found cookies :' + page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.cookie;
            }));
        }
        phantom.exit();
    });
}
```

Just save this script somewhere and call it

```
phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any read_cookies.js <some URL>
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. just provided you with a minimal script. As you can see, if  you run this script, you will only get cookies dropped by phantom itself or cookies set server side. No cookies are found which are dropped by js on site itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple setTimeout() before evaluating the page solves this.

```
window.setTimeout( function(){
   console.log('Found cookies :' + page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.cookie;
   }));
   phantom.exit();
},10000);
```